# Prime ideal becomes maximal after localization, then is it maximal to start with?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, localization

> Suppose $A$ is a commutative ring with $1$, $g\in A$, and $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal. We know that upon localising $\mathfrak{p}_g$ is maximal is $A_g$. (In particular it does not contain $g$.) Then is it true that $\mathfrak{p}$ is maximal in $A$?

We know that $A_g/\mathfrak{p}_g\cong (A/\mathfrak{p})_g$. If the LHS is a field so is RHS. Then it is forced that $A/\mathfrak{p}$ is also a field since we cannot get a field by inverting just one element (I know this is true for finitely generated $k$-algebras, but let me know if this is false in general). Thus, $\mathfrak{p}$ is a closed point.

Is my proof right or wrong. Meanwhile I am trying to show that $S^{-1}R$ is a field then $S$ is infinite (leaving the case when $R$ is already a field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a field by inverting one element. For instance let $A$ be the
subring of $\Bbb Q$ consisting of the fractions with odd denominator.
Then $\Bbb Q=A[1/2]$. A domain with $A[b]$ a field is called a
[G-domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-domain). These are used in proofs of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

Comment: Oh sweet. A lot of confusion is clear now. Thanks. Would you happen to know some more examples of these $G$-domains.

Comment: You can use the same trick: take a Dedekind domain and localise (or complete) at a prime ideal.

Comment: Now i am wondering if every such $G$-domain must be a valuation ring (since it looks like it is maximal with respect to inverting stuff in its field of fractions). I will read more about them. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Localization of a Dedekind domain at a non-zero prime is a DVR, not a field. Instead, if $A$ is a DVR with uniformizer $t$, then $A_t$ is a field, indeed. (In the example above $A=\mathbb Z_{(2)}$ is a DVR and $2$ is a uniformizer.)

Comment: @user26857 Exactly, localising or completing a Dedekind domain at a prime is one of the standard ways to construct a DVR.